# RACChannel: not seeing the two-way binding I expected

Tags: reactive-cocoa

(Open for comment from ReactiveCocoa guys on [GitHub](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/1023) as well.)

I'm trying out ReactiveCocoa in a very simple [RACTest (source is on GitHub)](https://github.com/cbowns/RACTest/) application in an attempt to firm up my theoretical understanding by actually using it.

I've got a `RACChannel` that, I *thought*, provided a two-way binding between a `RAC()`ed l-value and whatever I specified as arguments to `RACChannel`.

[My usage](https://github.com/cbowns/RACTest/blob/master/RACTest/MPSViewModel.m#L56) looks like:

```
// Map the ticker's accumulationEnabled property to self.paused.
RAC(self, paused) = [RACChannelTo(_ticker, accumulateEnabled) deliverOn:[RACScheduler mainThreadScheduler]];
```

I'm seeing changes flow one direction, from `_ticker.accumulateEnabled` to `self.paused`, but changes to `self.paused` aren't flowing back to `_ticker`.

Have I misunderstood `RACChannel`? What's it for, and how is this not the expected usage?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had misunderstood how to use `RACChannel`. Using `RACChannelTo` on both sides of the assignment works as expected:

`RACChannelTo(self, paused) = RACChannelTo(_ticker, accumulateEnabled);`

Main-thread delivery for changes to `self.paused` is a bit more complicated, but not terrible:

```
RACChannelTerminal *accumulateChannel = RACChannelTo(_ticker, accumulateEnabled);
RAC(self, paused) = [accumulateChannel deliverOn:RACScheduler.mainThreadScheduler];
[[RACObserve(self, paused) skip:1] subscribe:accumulateChannel];
```

(I'm still trying to understand why `skip:1` is necessary, but without it, RAC blows out the stack, so I'm keeping it [per the GitHub issue](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/1023#issuecomment-31051815).)

Comment: Did you find out what is the 'skip:1' ?

Comment: @PiratM yep, they answered it on Github (https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/1023#issuecomment-31053026): "The signals will send their initial values when you observe them. Since you only want to take the initial value from 1 side, you need to skip:1 to skip the initial value from the other side. Otherwise you'll be doing a=b; b=a."

Comment: "So by placing my skip:1 in [[RACObserve(self, paused) skip:1] subscribe:accumulateChannel];, I'm saying, "sync all changes across to self.paused after the first one", correct?" "In that case, you're saying "ignore the initial value of self.paused, but any time it changes, update _ticker.accumulateEnabled.""